# Chart element named Series1 could not be found in in the SeriesCollection

Tags: c#, charts

I am trying to show all employees who made transactions and how many every employee did between two days in my C# Windows Forms project. But it gives me an error as you see in title like `Chart element named Series1 could not be found in in the SeriesCollection`.
In my `Transaction` table I have such as `TransactionDate`, `staffId` and `offcourse`, in my `Employee` table I have `EmployeeId` and `FirstName`. Please help, this is my code inside a button event.

```
private void btnShowChartReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime stardate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerFrom.Value.ToString());
    DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerTo.Value.ToString());
    try
    {
        db = new BankiHsabEntities1();
        if (checkBoxAllserviceUpdate.Checked == true)
        {
            var result = (from u in db.Transaction
                          where u.TransactionDate >= stardate && 
                          u.TransactionDate <= enddate
                          group u by u.Employee.FirstName into g
                          select new
                          {
                              StaffId = g.Key,
                              Total = g.Count()
                           }).ToList();
            chart1.DataSource = result;

            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "StaffId";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Total";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Name = "Employees";

            chart1.DataBind();
            chart1.Show();
        }
}
```

Comment: 'Series1' is the default series if you have droped the chart from the toolbox unless you have cleared the series collection. We canät know what you did or how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first add series and refer to it:

```
var series = chart1.Series.Add("series1");
series.XValueMember = "StaffId";
series.YValueMembers = "Total";
series.Name = "Employees";
```